# How do I perform operations on variables omitting missing values

Tags: r, na.rm

I'm sure this question will seem a little bit basic for many but here is my problem:

I want to create a new variable which is an equation of other variables in RStudio:

```
D$satisfaction.conditions <- (D$imp.distance * D$sat.distance
                          + D$imp.salaire * D$sat.salaire
                          + D$imp.horaires * D$sat.horaires
                          + D$imp.chargetravail * D$sat.chargetravail
                          + D$imp.nbservice * D$sat.nbservice
                          + D$imp.locaux * D$sat.locaux
                          + D$imp.equipements * D$sat.equipements
                          + D$imp.ambiance * D$sat.ambiance
                          + D$imp.relationcollegues * D$sat.relationcollegues
                          + D$imp.stress * D$sat.stress)
```

The issue is that I have some missing values  in the equation, so I get a NA result for some observations.

I know that there is something to do with na.rm=TRUE but I can't find where to put it. I tried at the end but I get a

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"                          + D$imp.relationcollegues * D$sat.relationcollegues
                          + D$imp.stress * D$sat.stress) na.rm"
```

How can I get my new variable {satisfaction.conditions} ommiting NA values ?

Comment: Do you need the answer to be 0 (where NA exist) or do you want to calculate and then remove the NA rows?

Comment: I want to calculate without the NAs where there is missing values. I don't want the result to be NA.

Comment: In that case, you need to replace the NAs with 0s before running your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line of code before performing the calculation:

```
D[is.na(D)] <- 0
```

This will replace all the NAs with 0s